# Separating user input numbers in C#

Tags: c#, console-application

How can I separate a set of numbers in a console app in C# instead of asking the user for each individual number? E.g. instead of doing this...

```
        double first, second, third, fourth;

        Console.Write("Please enter first digit: ");
        first = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Please enter second digit: ");
        second = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Please enter third digit: ");
        third = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Please enter fourth digit: ");
        fourth = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: If its just single digits then you could use a `string` which is an array of chars. I doubt they will only be single digits tho. 2 cents.

Answer (score 5):

You can have them enter all digits at once with a separator of some sort (space in this example).

```
Console.Write("Please enter a bunch of digits separated by a space: ");
var allDigits = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
Double[] digits = allDigits.Select(d => Covert.ToDouble(d)).ToArray();
```

If your requirement is limited to `4 inputs` restrict the `allDigit` by using `IEnumerable<string>.Take(4)`

```
Console.Write("Please enter a bunch of digits separated by a space: ");
var allDigits = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Take(4);
Double[] digits = allDigits.Select(d => Covert.ToDouble(d)).ToArray();
```

Comment: You don't need Split(' '), just Split()

Comment: @CuongLe, true enough - but as an example I try to make it obvious how the separator can be changed.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of `array`, it can help you to faster read/write operation into variables

```
    double[] numbers = new double[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter {0} of 4 Number : ", i + 1);
        numbers[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    // numbers[0] = first
    // numbers[1] = second
    // numbers[2] = third
    // numbers[3] = fourth
```

If you really want to use four variables then, this can be the most short way :

```
    double first, second, third, fourth;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number : ");
        double input = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        switch (i)
        {

            case 1:
                first = input;
                break;

            case 2:
                second = input;
                break;

            case 3:
                third = input;
                break;
            case 4:
                fourth = input;
                break;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
Console.Write("Please enter numbers, comma-separated: ");
var numbers = Console.ReadLine()
    .Split(',')
    .Select(x => Double.Parse(x.Trim()))
    .ToList();
```

In real-life code though it would probably be better to use `TryParse` and throw an error back to the user.